# Polygon goes hey-wire when zoom is changed

Tags: zooming, polygon, google-fusion-tables

Here is the link that displays only one polygon.

https://www.google.com/fusiontables/embedviz?viz=MAP&q=select+col1+from+1PdVL8ltzXzHWbZI6MVWNghTz7sh9FKH9hw_YYYM+where+col0+%3D+412&h=false&lat=44.07068786477725&lng=-91.70146331134345&z=13&t=1&l=col1&y=2&tmplt=2

Increasing the zoom will make the shape to disappear first and later appear as a different polygon.

Here is the value for the geometry coloumn:

```
<Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><coordinates>-91.7038631654,44.0694374856,0 -91.7055532814,44.0738871339,0 -91.7054979683,44.0739665384,0 -91.7055402916,44.0741115336,0 -91.7056036015,44.0741019279,0 -91.7056387888,44.074121276,0 -91.7057645696,44.0744656962,0 -91.7056251503,44.0745755934,0 -91.7054229212,44.0739915748,0 -91.7037600839,44.0695990536,0 -91.7036568735,44.0695519885,0 -91.7031499848,44.0695794019,0 -91.7031311599,44.0695869489,0 -91.7031138294,44.0695961708,0 -91.7030982784,44.069606916,0 -91.7030847624,44.0696190077,0 -91.7030735039,44.0696322471,0 -91.7030646879,44.0696464165,0 -91.7030584595,44.0696612828,0 -91.7030549211,44.0696766016,0 -91.7030541309,44.0696921209,0 -91.7030561019,44.0697075855,0 -91.7030410581,44.0694768048,0 -91.7038631654,44.0694374856,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon>
```

Is there a way to correct this behavior?

Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem with the FusionTablesLayer tile generator.  If I [export it using the FusionTables API v1.0 and render it as a native Google Maps API v3 polygon](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=44.072353&lng=-91.705089&zoom=16&type=m&tablequery=SELECT%20%20col1%20FROM%20&tableid=1PdVL8ltzXzHWbZI6MVWNghTz7sh9FKH9hw_YYYM&where=col0%20=%20412), it seems to work at all zoom levels.

A couple of options:

1. you could try reversing the winding direction, that has helped in some weird cases like this
2. you could try simplifying the polygon (although it seems pretty simple to me), but again that has helped in some weird cases like this.

The previous instances I am referring to were discussed in the [Fusion Tables User Group](https://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group), couldn't find them with a quick search.

Here is [one of the threads I was remembering](http://groups.google.com/group/fusion-tables-users-group/browse_frm/thread/9e37c4238fd7346/9857a1ac5fc7b426?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=polygons+simplify#9857a1ac5fc7b426)